# How can we change php backend api url according to application language?

Tags: java, php, android

My app has a PHP backend and I want to change BASE_URL according to device language. How should I edit my code?

```
package com.xxxxx.haber.config;

public class Config {

  public static final String BASE_URL = "http://admin.xxxxxx.com/api/";
  public static final String TOKEN_APP = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  public static final String BASE_URL_WEATHER = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
  public static final String KEY_APP_WEATHER = "xxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

Comment: you can pass your language as parameter in api so php dev. will provide you url according to your language.

Comment: Agree with The Ravi. Question is why do you want to do that? You'll have to make request to the same API in the end

Comment: Thanks ,mythoughtfulness :)